# Uninstall one Anaconda version2 from linux post installation of Anaconda 3 on linux ec2

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed anaconda 2 (by mistake) and anaconda 3 in linux ec2 instance. I am able to run jupyter notebook after spending a lot of time. But when I run jupyter notebook , i can see python version 2.x

I am a beginner to linux so how to make jupyter notebook run on python 3.x .

If I have to uninstall Anaconda2 from ec2 , how do I do it safely. Also , I fear I would lose access to Jupyter notebook if i uninstall Anaconda2.

I would want to run jupyter notebook on python 3 without much hassles and risks to current jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Double check the ~/.bashrc or alike, anaconda usually add its path there. 
You should be able to switch from one version to the other by modifying that path.

Comment: Might be silly to ask (considering I am beginner). How do I check this and upgrade . Can you list the command please ?